# visual studio 2015 not stopping on exception line of code

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2015

I just installed visual studio on my desktop and was creating a test solution to learn my way around. I created a solution with 2 projects, one of an IDataReader implementation of a CSV reader and another windows form app to display the reader in a datagridview.

The Reader generates an exception as expected, but it does not stop on the line of code which threw the exception. The reader gets instantiated correctly. But when I go to load it into a datatable it throws an exception on Table.Load(Reader)

The exception is occurring somewhere inside the reader but it is not stopping where the exception is actually occurring.

My dataReader looks like this:

```
    public class DelimitedReader : IDataReader{....lots of code here...}
```

My form accesses the Delimitedreader like this:

```
    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DelimitedReader Reader = new DelimitedReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            DataTable Table = new DataTable("Data");

            Table.Load(Reader);<<<<<<<<Exception stops on this line of code
            Grid.DataSource = Table;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have:

- turned on the CLR exceptions in the "Exception Settings Window"
- made sure "Debug Info" was set to Full on both projects
- Turned on XML documentation for both, which I think is unnecessary

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your reader does a throw new Exception. This causes VS to stop at a higher level exception handler.

Comment: This is correct. the Exception was coming from inside the DataReader  somewhere due to malformed SchemaTable which is required when loading a datatable from a IDataReader.

The other error which I corrected was the GetValues method was not properly returning the array of objects representing the values in the array.